# How To Make A Invite Tracker Bot With MongoDB With Removeinvites Feature

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

I know what to do

I have to use guildMemberAdd and guildMemberRemove Events.
In a help server, they said i want to use a database
So my choice was mongodb
And I Dont Know How To Do

If Someone Can Help Me With Code Snippets
It Will be a real help

Any help will be appriciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here you have example schema or storing invites alongside with data about the invites themselves

```
const inviteSchema = new Schema({
  code: String,
  uses: Number,
  leaves: { type: Number, default: 0 }, // this part line is needed only for second part of answer
  temporary: Boolean,
  maxUses: Number,
  inviterId: String,
  guildId: String
  created: String,
  expiresTimestamp: String || null,
})
```

on booting up you would have to load up all of those invites that were created while bot was offline
so in ready event
next event would be guildMemberAdd event
to update the entry with new value for `Uses`
don't just add one, as there could be joins when the bot was offline

If you would like to make it so the number of invites is decreased as members leave the server
The example simple memberSchema where you would store code of invite, guild where the invite is from and memberId

```
const memberSchema = new Schema({
  code: String,
  guildId: String,
  memberId: String,
})
```

in here you would be using guildMemberRemove
though the tiny problem in here would be that the number of invites would not be decreased when the bot is offline
to "fix" this you would have to loop thru all elements of memberSchema checking if the person is in there or not
and then update the entry in inviteSchema

Comment: Can i have your discord pls i need some more help

Comment: how to add values to them??

First TIme Using Mongo
So I dunno

Comment: the main guy who records video on this support server that you mentioned showed that in one of his videos for discord.js v14 series

Comment: Discord username and tag of him pls